# R - Reformat list

Tags: java, r, gcc, rjava

I'm trying to format a list so that it can be interpreted by another function. I have lists of vectors of tokenized words and their parts-of-speech tags like so:

```
> tokens
[[1]]
[1] "This" "is"   "a"    "test" "!"   

[[2]]
[1] "This" "is"   "a"    "test" "!"   

> pos_tags
[[1]]
[1] "DT"  "VBZ" "DT"  "NN"  "."  

[[2]]
[1] "DT"  "VBZ" "DT"  "NN"  "."
```

I'd like to reformat them into a list like the one below. This process should be reproducible for lists of any length.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "This"

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "DT"


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "is"

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "VBZ"


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[1]][[3]][[2]]
[1] "DT"


[[1]][[4]]
[[1]][[4]][[1]]
[1] "test"

[[1]][[4]][[2]]
[1] "NN"


[[1]][[5]]
[[1]][[5]][[1]]
[1] "!"

[[1]][[5]][[2]]
[1] "."



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "This"

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "DT"


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "is"

[[2]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "VBZ"


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]][[3]][[2]]
[1] "DT"


[[2]][[4]]
[[2]][[4]][[1]]
[1] "test"

[[2]][[4]][[2]]
[1] "NN"


[[2]][[5]]
[[2]][[5]][[1]]
[1] "!"

[[2]][[5]][[2]]
[1] "."
```

Any instruction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to do a double `Map` in `R`

```
Map(function(x, y) Map(list, as.list(x), as.list(y)), tokens, pos_tags)
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[[1]][[1]][[1]]
#[1] "This"

#[[1]][[1]][[2]]
#[1] "DT"


#[[1]][[2]]
#[[1]][[2]][[1]]
#[1] "is"

#[[1]][[2]][[2]]
#[1] "VBZ"


#[[1]][[3]]
#[[1]][[3]][[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[1]][[3]][[2]]
#[1] "DT"


#[[1]][[4]]
#[[1]][[4]][[1]]
#[1] "test"

#[[1]][[4]][[2]]
#[1] "NN"


#[[1]][[5]]
#[[1]][[5]][[1]]
#[1] "!"

#[[1]][[5]][[2]]
#[1] "."



#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[[2]][[1]][[1]]
#[1] "This"

#[[2]][[1]][[2]]
#[1] "DT"


#[[2]][[2]]
#[[2]][[2]][[1]]
#[1] "is"

#[[2]][[2]][[2]]
#[1] "VBZ"


#[[2]][[3]]
#[[2]][[3]][[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]][[3]][[2]]
#[1] "DT"


#[[2]][[4]]
#[[2]][[4]][[1]]
#[1] "test"

#[[2]][[4]][[2]]
#[1] "NN"


#[[2]][[5]]
#[[2]][[5]][[1]]
#[1] "!"

#[[2]][[5]][[2]]
#[1] "."
```

#### data

```
tokens <- list(c("This", "is", "a", "test", "!"), c("This", "is", "a", "test", "!"))

pos_tags <- list(c("DT", "VBZ", "DT", "NN", "."), c("DT", "VBZ", "DT", "NN", "."))
```

Comment: I ran this and got the warning: Warning messages:
1: In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
2: In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter

Comment: @ChristopherCostello  I am using two lists of same length as in your question (please check the `data` I used)

Answer (score 1):

```
Map(function(x,y)as.list(c(rbind(x,y))),tokens,pos_tags)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "This"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "DT"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "is"

[[1]][[4]]
[1] "VBZ"

[[1]][[5]]
[1] "a"

[[1]][[6]]
[1] "DT"

[[1]][[7]]
[1] "test"

[[1]][[8]]
[1] "NN"

[[1]][[9]]
[1] "!"

[[1]][[10]]
[1] "."


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "This"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "DT"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "is"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "VBZ"

[[2]][[5]]
[1] "a"

[[2]][[6]]
[1] "DT"

[[2]][[7]]
[1] "test"

[[2]][[8]]
[1] "NN"

[[2]][[9]]
[1] "!"

[[2]][[10]]
[1] "."
```